# Update status column on basis of multiple id in one table

Tags: javascript, laravel

i have subjects table with status column and parent_id column so from view page if i click on active button change the status to active/inactive..
So now if i click on subject active button it should change status of that child subjects too..

here is my code:

```
public function updateStatus(subject $subject)
{

    $subject_id = $subject->id;
    $subjects = Subject::where(['parent_id' => $subject_id])->get();
    $subjects->status = !$subjects->status;
    $subjects->save();
    return redirect()->route('subject.index');
}
```

I am storing the main id in parent_id column.So if i change status of main id it should change status of related parent_id  column status also. if it is 1 it should change to 0. if it is 0 it should change to 1.
Can anyone help me to solve this..TIA

Comment: `save()` accepts Eloquent model instance, not a collection. So change `get()` to `first()`

Comment: so whats the mistake i did

Comment: If you want to update all record that has parent_id, then use update method insted of save method

Comment: Call to a member function update() on bool getting this error from foreach loop

Comment: It will be something like `$subjects = Subject::where('parent_id', $subject_id)->update(['status' => $subject->status]);` this is enough for update your query, so delete the save method if it work.

Comment: what if i want to make introvert condition? like if it is 0 make it as 1..if it is 1 make 0

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, first, you need to add parent data to your query:

```
$subjects = Subject::where('parent_id', $subject_id)->orWhere('id', $subject_id)->get();
```

Since this is a collection, you should create a loop to update each item. BTW, Laravel may have a built-in function for this, but I don't know.

```
foreach($subjects as $subject) {
   $subject->update([
      'status' => !$subject->status
   ]);
}
```

Comment: yes exactly the same way i am looking for..but when i use your code i am getting this error.

Comment: Add [status] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Subject].

Comment: I didn't get any error like this. So I'm not sure. What do you have in $fillable array on Subject Model?

Comment: i dont have anything in fillable so now added liek this in my model 
    protected $fillable = ['status'];

Comment: if i added that i am getting this error 
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is execute two queries, one for update status 0 where status is 1 :

```
Subject::where('parent_id', $subject_id)->where('status', 1)->update(['status' => 0]);
```

and other for change status 0 to 1 for the id you received

```
Subject::where('parent_id', $subject_id)->where('status', 0)->update(['status' => 1]);
```

So finally your code will be look like :

```
public function updateStatus(subject $subject)
{
    $subject_id = $subject->id;
    $subject = Subject::where('parent_id', $subject_id)->where('status', 1)->update(['status' => 0]);
    $subject = Subject::where('parent_id', $subject_id)->where('status', 0)->update(['status' => 1]);
    return redirect()->route('subject.index');
}
```

Comment: so can i keep two in 1 function

Comment: What the error you got? Give me the output of `dd($subject);`

Comment: 3 is the result if dd($subject)

Comment: Try with remove the quatation on both query, 
Like  `['status' => '0']` to `['status' => 0]`

Comment: I updated my question. You added `status` on your model's fillable property?